# Changing a button to say "Loading" with a loading animation on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have created a Vue button that displays "Load More" and then "Loading..." when clicked and loading more content. But, I would now like to add another component being a loading animation next to the "Loading." The button works completely fine, but I just would like to add that animation alongside the word "loading."

I have tried using Vue's ref tag, but have not had much luck in successfully using that in my method.

Loader.vue:

```
<template>
  <div
    ref="sdcVueLoader"
    class="sdc-vue-Loader"
  >
    Loading...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Loader'
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<Button
  :disabled="clicked"
  @click="loadMore"
>
  {{ loadMoreText }}
</Button>

<script>
import Button from './components/Button'
import Loader from './components/Loader'

export default {
  name: 'ParentApp',
  components: {
    Button,
    Loader
  },
  data () {
    return {
      loadMoreText: 'Load More',
      clicked: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore () {
      if ... {
        this.page += 1
        this.loadMoreText = 'Loading...' + this.$refs.sdcVueLoader
        this.clicked = true
        this.somerequest().then(resp => {
          this.clicked = false
          this.loadMoreText = 'Load More'
        })
        return this.loadMoreText
      }
    }
</script>
```

I am hoping for the button to continue working as it is now, but now to also have the "Loader" component displaying next to "Loading..." when the button is clicked in the app.vue loadMore method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do anything with any form of complexity in html, it is best to move it over to your template. In your case, you have two states: It is either loading, or it is not loading. So lets create a variable `loading` that is either `true` or `false`.

```
data () {
  return {
    loading: false,
    page: 1,
  }
},
methods: {
  async loadMore () {
    if (this.loading) {
      return;
    }

    this.page += 1;
    this.loading = true;
    const response = await this.somerequest();

    this.loading = false;
    // Oddly enough, we do nothing with the response
  }
}
```

Now, in the template use a `v-if` with a `v-else`:

```
<button
  :disabled="loading"
  @click="loadMore"
>
  <template v-if="loading">
    <icon name="loader" />
    Loading...
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    Load more
  </template>
</button>
```

If you want to move the logic to a different component, you have two options:

- Add `loading` as a prop to that different component, and move the template code to that component
- Use a slot and pass the html directly into your loading button. This is especially useful if you have several different configurations, and don't want to deal with increasingly complex configuration options just to accommodate them all.

Comment: Thanks for the help!